# как ограничить клиентский доступ к функционалу сайта?

Tags: reactjs

Есть сайт на стеке Mongo, Express, React + redux, NodeJS(MERN), он клиентский и регистрация на нем через соц сети, хотя сервер тоже регистрирует параллельно. Так вот хотелось бы узнать варианты хотя бы примерные и абстрактные-  как ограничить открытость кода с урезанием функционала, например ввода платных услуг и так далее. 
Первым в голову приходит давать доступ к заранее подготовленным, урезанным файлам и скриптам то есть к другим, но я не представляю как это на React сделать, после сборки в продакшен там все ровно будет все сплошняком

Answer (score 0):

То что отдается клиентам, включая реакт, не может содержать секретной информации. Вся информация, которая требует защиты, должна храниться на сервере и отдаваться клиенту по запросу в случае подтверждения им прав на нёё.

Обычно делается апи на сервере, которое проверяет имеет ли право пользователь получить запрашиваемую информацию по запросу и отправляет её в случае подтверждения. Клиент далее эту информацию отображает.

Comment: дело в том что на клиенте вся логика, именно клиент работает с браузера с API Youtube, VK, FB.... вопрос наверное не так поставил... вот думаю как функционал урезать